# When inserting objects into a type-safe heterogeneous container, why do we need the class reference?

Tags: java, class

I'm checking out the heterogeneous container pattern from Bloch's Effective Java and I'm trying to determine why the class reference is needed when inserting objects into the heterogeneous container. Can't I use `instance.getClass()` to get this reference? Isn't JPA's [entity manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) an example of this?

```java
interface BlochsHeterogeneousContainer {

    <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, T instance);

    <T> T get(Class<T> clazz);
}

interface AlternativeHeterogeneousContainer {

    // Class<T> not needed because we can use instance.getClass()
    <T> void put(T instance);

    <T> T get(Class<T> clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't do that, as it won't give you class of reference type in case of inheritance, rather the class of actual object type.

Consider this example:

```
Number num = new Integer(4);
System.out.println(num.getClass());
```

this will print:

```
class java.lang.Integer
```

and not `java.lang.Number`.

Comment: +1 Exactly, so the interface allows for `put(Number.class, num)` or `put(Integer.class, num)` as appropriate.

Comment: `put(Integer.class, num)` would throw a compiler error. This makes sense because the types of the arguments are (Class<Integer>, Number). You can't set T to Integer because Number is not a Integer. You can't set T to number because Class<Integer> is not a Class<Number>. Nonetheless, it is still useful to have a type parameter since you can do things like `put(Object.class, num)`.  In this case, T is set to Object (and all Numbers are Objects so it works).

Answer (score 0):

I actually always need other approach (with .getClass()), so I suppose both implementations could be useful..

```
class Favorites {
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void putFavorite(Class<T> type, T instance) {
        favorites.put(Objects.requireNonNull(type), instance);
    }

    public <T> void putFavorite(T instance) {
        favorites.put(instance.getClass(), instance);
    }

    public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> type) {
        return type.cast(favorites.get(type));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Favorites favorites = new Favorites();

        Number num = new Integer(4);

        favorites.putFavorite(Number.class, num);   //ADDS Number -> 4
        //favorites.putFavorite(Integer.class, num);  //Error: no suitable method found for putFavorite(java.lang.Class<java.lang.Integer>,java.lang.Number)
        favorites.putFavorite(num); //ADDS Integer -> 4

        System.out.println(favorites.favorites);    //{class java.lang.Integer=4, class java.lang.Number=4}
    }
}
```